# Insert while(Expression): to complete Do statement need assistance

Tags: java, arrays

I have two problems one is a syntax error for money. I have tried to define money and also define it as an int but it still get Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token "money", @ expected after this token      line 23 Java Problem. I also get the [] to complete dimensions and insert identifier to complete method Head Name. 
import java.util.*;

```
public class Blackjack{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ;}
        private static int money;// the money the player bets with
        private static int bet;//how much the user wants to bet
        private static int AceCounter;//how many aces are in the user's hand
        private static ArrayList<Card> hand;//represents the user's hand
        private static int handvalue;//the value of the user's hand
        private static String name; //name of the user
        private static int cash; // how much money in the bet
            {

         while (money>0) {
             money = 1000; 
         }}

       money money("You have " + money + " dollars.")); 
    do {
```

The second is the array for some reason i keep getting an error stating that I need to insert a while expression to complete do statement

```
while(!isyesorno(answer))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please answer yes or no.");
                    answer = yesorno.nextLine();
                }
        if(answer.equals("no"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
        System.out.println("Your cash is: "+cash);//If no new game then game ends and tells them how much they have won or lost.

        if(cash==0)
        {
            System.out.println("You ran out of cash!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enjoy your winnings, "+name+"!");
        }
     }
}}
```

Comment: your code is outside of a method, that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have lot of concern on your question :

1. Your `static void main` method is closed immediately that is why you are getting this error.
2. I see lots of error in your code. just to mention, 
   [image]

This clearly shows that you haven't tried to debug it yourself. It is very basic of Java Programming. I would recommend you to Got to Oracle Java Doc page([while-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)) and type exactly what is written there.

Comment: These are only parts of the code not full code. I have tried to debug it but it told me to close the static void. That is why it is closed.

Comment: All of your code block should be inside static void main. It is saying to close means keep your all code inside it then close it.

Comment: @Coded_overflow the compiler will not guide you through writing syntactically valid code, that is something you should be able to do on your own and *understand* what is valid and what is not. neither adding nor removing the `;}` is valid .You simply need to get back to the drawing board and write a method that does what you need and define some fields you need outside that method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had thought of it but it seemed it would lead to too many static